# How to build a 2 column view in bootstrap with large textarea on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

Hi everyone, I am trying to build a view like in the added pic.I would like to build a view ( display form ) with 2 columns that looks like the attached picture. I have a 2 column input form that looks like this already, but I'm not sure what elements to use to build the view with. I used input elements for the input form. I'd like it to have a layout like:

```
       textbox

field1           field2

field3          field4
```

What should the HTML look like to build the view I'm looking for?

Thanks in advance,

Bill

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the grid sizing classes (`.span1` to `.span12`):

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="controls">
        <textarea class="span12" type="text"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input class="span6" type="text"/>
        <input class="span6" type="text"/>
    </div>
    <div class="controls controls-row">
        <input class="span6" type="text"/>
        <input class="span6" type="text"/>
    </div>    
</div>
```

​**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pCffu/2)**.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make the fields into a 2 row table? Like so:

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="30">

</textarea>
<table border="none">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="field1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="field2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="field3" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="field4" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi guys, Thanks for the answers. I am not experienced with HTML so I need to ask a basic question here: I am trying to make a view, which I will populate from a DB, not a form ( I may have been confusing ). Should I be using input elements? I don't want the output to be changeable by the user. Thanks - Bill

Comment: It doesn't have to be input tag. You may use span as well. Can you provide your populating script? Maybe we can help out better if we know exactly how your fields are being set.