# Basic html approach: what elements should I use to build a view

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

This is a follow up question to [How to build a 2 column view in bootstrap with large textarea on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12116007/how-to-build-a-2-column-view-in-bootstrap-with-large-textarea-on-top).

I appreciated the answers, but I am not experienced with HTML so I need to ask a basic question here: I am trying to make a view ( which I will populate from a DB ), not a form.  Should I be using input elements or some other html element? I don't want the view fields to be changeable by the user. Again I will likely be trying to make a table like so:

```
<textarea rows="2" cols="30">

</textarea>
<table border="none">
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="field1" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="field2" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="text" name="field3" /></td>
<td><input type="text" name="field4" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance ,

Bill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to load some data from database like (user details or what so ever) and you want to display it to user but dont want it modify it?

So basically, use forms when you want user **to add new** information **or edit** existing one, you could also disable inputs if you dont want to let him edit them - but IMHO this is really confusing design approach most of the times for users - at least I would not prefer it when you are going to disable full page of inputs :)

When you actually want to show something to user like plain text you use paragraphs `<p>Some text here</p>` etc. I suspect you have started to learn to use HTML via twitter bootstrap and are bit confused.

To get started with HTML I suggest that you will go through all chapters of this tutorial https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML

After playing around with that tutorial and examples, get back to twitter bootstrap so it could open up for you bit better, good luck!

Comment: W3Schools is not the finest source to learn HTML from (see http://w3fools.com/). I suggest the author to use MDN https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML instead

Comment: @Pavlo Mykhalov yes thnx, I should have remembered it, updated my answer